# Fade in a dynamic text

Tags: jquery, fadein

Not sure why this isn't working, but I have a timer which loads in the numbers like so:

```
 function startTimer(num){
  count = num;
  countdown = setInterval(function(){

     $("#timer p.seconds").text([count]).fadeIn(300);
    count--;
  }, 1000);
 };

$(document).on('click', '.step3-btn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    startTimer(30);
});

<p class="seconds"></p>
```

I would like the initial number to fade in slowly, but that code isn't working. It just shows without the fade.

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: Ok, I just added more code

Comment: Have you tried putting a `.hide()` before the `.fadeIn(300)`? `$("#timer p.seconds").text([count]).hide().fadeIn(300);`

Comment: thanks but that fades in every number, I only want to fade in the initial one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check to see if the first number is the upper limit and only fade in that by hiding it first.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qWNuZ/)**

```
function startTimer(num) {
     count = num;
     countdown = setInterval(function () {
         if(count==num){$("p.seconds").text([count]).hide().fadeIn(300);}
         else{$("p.seconds").text([count]).fadeIn(300);}         
         count--;
     }, 1000);
 };
startTimer(30);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/pqUYS/

```
var count = 10,
    next;
(next = function() {
    if ( count > 0 ) {
        $("p.seconds").hide().text(count--).fadeIn(1000, next);
    }
})();
```

**Updated Fiddle**

Only fades on first number
http://jsfiddle.net/pqUYS/3/

Comment: thanks but I only want to fade in the initial number, not every number.